# Unlink - Permission denied. How to resolve?

Tags: php, file-upload, unlink

I want to delete a file using `unlink` but I receive a Warning Message,

```
Warning: unlink(uploads/487001/): Permission denied in
```

When I check on the folder, the file is successfully deleted. Below are the codes that I did,

**Uploads.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['mc'])) {
    $file = $sno . "-" . date("Ymd") . "-" . $_FILES['mc']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['mc']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['mc']['size'];
    $folder = "uploads/" . $sno . "/";
    $final_file = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($file));

    if ($file_size <= 0) {
        $error= "<span class=\"w3-text-red\">Select a file to upload</span>";
    }

    if (!is_dir($folder)) {
        mkdir($folder, 0777, true);
    }

    if (move_uploaded_file($file_location, $folder . $final_file)) {
        $upload = true; 
    }
}
```

**Delete.php**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){

    if(empty($_POST['checkbox'])){
        $error = "<span class=\"w3-container w3-text-red\">No data selected</span><p/>";
    } elseif(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
        $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
        $files = $_POST['file'];
        $path = 'uploads/' . $_SESSION['staff_no'] . '/';

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            if (file_exists($path.$file)) {
                chmod($path.$file, 0777);
                unlink($path.$file);
            } 
        }
    }

// Other validations & Delete row from database
```

This is the file structure,

```
Project Folder > Uploads > user_id > files
```

May I know what is the mistakes?

Comment: you're trying to unlink folder, you could use `rmdir` for this case. http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php

Comment: @JaredChu will that remove the folder as well? I want to delete the file only but keep the folder of the user

Comment: In case that `487001` is a file, it should be `unlink(uploads/487001)` instead of `unlink(uploads/487001/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does **$POST['file'**] is holding? If it is an array then check for blanks / null values as well. **file_exists()** will return true in case of **$file** is blank, but then your path will end up with **uploads/487001/** and you will get that warning.

Comment: It is holding an array of files name

Comment: In that case add one more check for blank value.above this line of code  if(strlen($file) > 0){
    if((file_exists($path.$file)) { ... }
}

Answer (score 0):

Use this way, it will remove file from Server as well as Database.

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){

    if($file_path) {
         chmod($file_path, 0777);
         unlink($file_path);
       $query = "DELETE FROM medias WHERE mediaId = '".$_POST["delete"]."'";
       $statement= $db->delete($query);   
     }
}
```